# Google AppEngine Key exception

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa

I have two classes, CarRentalCompany

```
@Entity
public class CarRentalCompany {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CarRentalCompany.class.getName());

    @Id
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Car> cars;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<CarType> carTypes = new ArrayList<>(); //TODO: kan betere datastructuur zijn

    /***************
     * CONSTRUCTOR *
     ***************/

    public CarRentalCompany()
    {
         // DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR
    }

    public CarRentalCompany(String name, List<Car> cars) {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "<{0}> Car Rental Company {0} starting up...", name);
        setName(name);
        this.cars = cars;
        for(Car car:cars) 
            carTypes.add(car.getType());
    }
    ...
}
```

and CarType

```
@Entity
public class CarType {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    private String name;
    private int nbOfSeats;
    private boolean smokingAllowed;
    private double rentalPricePerDay;
    //trunk space in liters
    private float trunkSpace;

    /***************
     * CONSTRUCTOR *
     ***************/

    public CarType()
    {

    }

    public CarType(String name, int nbOfSeats, float trunkSpace, double rentalPricePerDay, boolean smokingAllowed) {
        this.name = name;
        this.nbOfSeats = nbOfSeats;
        this.trunkSpace = trunkSpace;
        this.rentalPricePerDay = rentalPricePerDay;
        this.smokingAllowed = smokingAllowed;
    }
```

When running the application, it throws the following exception:

> NucleusFatalUserException: Attempt to assign child with key
>   "CarType(6614661952700416)" to parent with key
>   "CarRentalCompany("Hertz")". Parent keys are immutable

What do I need to do to get the key of the CarType right?

Answer (score 0):

You are not [persisting](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-persist-and-merge/) your CarRentalCompany entity before adding CarType entity. See a 
similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29640951/10553701). The persist operation must be used only for new entities. An entity is new when it has never been associated with a database row, meaning that there is no table record in the database to match the entity in question.